# Tor exited during startup on Windows 10 Pro

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

After upgrading from Win10Home to Win10Pro on two PC and updating Tor, Tor still keeps working only on one of them.
On the second one, instead of working during startup, Tor displays the message:
Tor exited during startup. This might be due to an error in your torrc file, a bug in Tor or another program on your system, or faulty hardware. Until you fix the underlying problem and restart Tor, Tor Browser will not start.

Other symptoms:
Never seen before – the browser works with freezing during navigation if try to enter the tor options (or press 'Tor Network Settings');
I can't either enter the tor options (via 'Tor' in the sidebar), therefore I can't see any logs.

The torrc file is empty (as is by default).
Trying to stop/remove tor services, reinstallations, and such don't solve or affect the problem.
As mentioned, I can't enter the tor menu, the other options are still available though.

Update:

Fortunately, after the current tor and windows updates, the issue has been fixed itself.

Comment: Please attach an error log, so I will be able to help you

Comment: As mentioned: 
> I can't either enter the tor options (via 'Tor' in the sidebar), therefore I can't see any logs.